# java get Test Annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, reflection

in my project (ReflectionProject) i search  all Tests method in all class in a generic JAR (JarTest1.jar) (Search all jar in a specific folder e.g. public static String pathJars="C:\Users\G.Ventura\Desktop\test_jar" )

In project JarTest1:

IF Tests methods are in Test Folder (Junit Test) when in my ReflectionProject do:

```
Annotation annTest = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
```

I obtain annTest=null always.

IF Tests methods are in src/main/java/  my ReflectionProject work correctly infact :

```
Annotation annTest = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
annTest != null..
```

For package JarTest1 with Test folder contains i add at pom.xml also "maven-assembly-plugin" for to obtain 2 jar: one with classes in Test Folder and another without Test Folder.

Why? getAnnotation method of Reflection class dont work for Test folder ?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: with maven-assembly plugin i create 2 jar JarTest1.jar and JarTest1-test.jar.  JarTest1-test.jar ha also classes test in src/main/test folder..

Comment: Sorry, I started to write my comment before your edit. I didn't understand something, you said that you've already tried to inspect JarTest1-test.jar, and checked if your compiled test classes files e.g. `MyTest.class` were there?

Comment: yes in jar there also Test classes.. The problem is that "getAnnotationMethod" dont work!  this is my code (incomplete): https://pastebin.com/3YG2gCQV
With debug i view that classname and method arre correct but Reflection dont captures @Test

Comment: no is an external file..my ReflectionProject  search all jar in a specific path  e.g. public static String pathJars="C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\test_jar"

Comment: yes sorry, didn't see the edit again. I'm going to take a look and come later if I find something

Comment: Do you have different `Test` annotations in scope?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved Test.class is for only junit5 but JarTest1 is written in JUNIT4 so:

change this row:

```
Annotation annTest = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
```

with:

```
Annotation annTestj4 = method.getAnnotation(org.junit.Test.class); //junit4
Annotation annTestj5 = method.getAnnotation(org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class);//junit5

Annotation annTestFactory = method.getAnnotation(TestFactory.class);
Annotation annTestDisabled = method.getAnnotation(Disabled.class);

if ((annTestj4 != null || annTestFactory != null || annTestj5 != null) && annTestDisabled == null) {
    testMethods.add(method.getName());
}
```